# Strange tags in Google Tag Manager?

Tags: google-analytics, google-tag-manager, gtag.js

My Measurement ID is `G-XH******`. I see a few strange things in my Google Tag Manager account:

## 1. In GTM there is one tag starting with GT-

[image]
[image]

## 2. In Tag Assistance there is another one starting with G-

[image]
[image]

I guess the second one is a GA tag automatically created when I use the Setup Assistant in my old UA property, but I don’t know how to identify it or remove it. Do you know what these are?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## 1. A single Google tag can have multiple tag IDs

From [Google tag ID: Definition - Tag Manager Help](https://support.google.com/tagmanager/answer/12326985?hl=en):

> A tag ID is an identifier that you put on your page to load a given Google tag. Examples of tag IDs include GT-XXXXXXXXX, G-XXXXXXXXX, and AW-XXXXXXXXX. A single Google tag can have multiple tag IDs.

> The first ID is the "main" ID, but the IDs can be used interchangeably when adding the Google tag to your website.

[image: An illustration demonstrating where to locate Tag IDs on Google tag.]

I guess this is to make it easier for backward-compatibility with the old system, in which each Google marketing product (Google Analytics, Google Ads) has a different code for the same website, rather than unifying them in one [Google tag](https://support.google.com/analytics/topic/12403939?hl=en).

## 2. When reusing existing UA `analytics.js` tag, a new Google tag `gtag.js` is created

When you check this box, a new Google tag `gtag.js` is created:

[image]

From [[GA4] About connected site tags - Analytics Help](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/9973999?hl=en):

> An additional gtag(‘config’, ‘G-XXXXXXXXXX’) call is made (without any parameters), which downloads a Google Analytics 4 tag container and sends an automatic page_view event to the Google Analytics 4 property.